# Transform attribute applied to SVG <symbol> works in Firefox, but not in Chrome

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG icon I want to reuse, and would like to transform it first before doing so. Here is a simplified version of the issue I'm facing:

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.circle {
  fill: green;
  transform: scale(3)
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  
  <symbol id="circle" transform="scale(2)" class="circle">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
  </symbol>
    
  <use href="#circle"/>

</svg>
```

The green circle is properly sized in Firefox, whether I use inline styling or a class, but in Chrome, the `fill` attribute is applied, but not `transform`, class or inline, it remains small. A comparison screenshot:

[image]

Of course, I could work around it by applying transformations to each `<use>` element, but I'd like to understand why it doesn't work, because [in the MDN docs, the `<symbol>` page lists `transform` as a legal attribute.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol#Attributes)
Perhaps the issue is that `transform` [is not inherited](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-property), but it still works in Firefox, so maybe the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: The symbol is meant to be a symbol. Keep the symbol simple with no stylings (fill stroke transform...) and style the `<use>`. Also is very useful to add a viewBox to the symbol so that you can give the`<use>` a width and a height. Use this instead of transformation.

Comment: This is a new feature of SVG 2. In SVG 1.1 symbols didn't support a transform attribute. I guess Chrome simply hasn't implemented this part of SVG 2 yet. You could always try raising an issue in Chrome's issue tracking system.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks! That conclusively explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robert Longson pointed out in the comments, `<symbol>` elements supporting the `transform` property is a new SVG 2 feature that hasn't made its way to Chrome yet.